# gulp.src base option apply on one array item

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm using the `base` option in my `gulp.src`
I want the base will apply on **one item** in my src **array** but not in rest:
In my case:

```
   gulp.src(['./languages/*.json', '../../../Configuration/Client/help/*/**'],{base:'../../../Configuration/Client'})
                .pipe(zip('my_zip_file.zip'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
```

I need that `{base:'../../../Configuration/Client'}` will apply **only on second item** in the array (`'../../../Configuration/Client/help/*/**'`) and **not on the first item**.

It's seems like the `base` option cannot be separated per array item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your npm package: **event-stream**

Then in your gulpfile.js:

```
  var eventStream = require('event-stream');
  var jsonFiles = gulp.src('./languages/*.json');
  var helpfiles = gulp.src('../../../Configuration/Client/help/*/**',{base:'../../../Configuration/Client'});

  eventStream.merge(jsonFiles,helpfiles)
      .pipe(zip('myZipFile.zip'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./languages/'))
```